# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps') Flutter and Dart issue

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, typeerror

I am having issues with a project I am working on that implements Google Maps into a flutter app. Here is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Shipping App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MapScreen(),
    );
   }
 }

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override 
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.773972, -122.431297),
    zoom: 11.5,
  );

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Shipping App'),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I followed the tutorial posted by Google on how to implement maps with flutter and have created my API keys, updated the AndroidManifest.xml and AppDelegate.swift files as well as the pubspec.yaml with the correct dependencies.

An Observatory debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:57299/_jOFNoFp7u0=
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building GoogleMap(dirty, state:
_GoogleMapState#b748d):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

The relevant error-causing widget was:
GoogleMap GoogleMap:file:///C:/Users/Spencer/google_maps_in_flutter/lib/main.dart:38:13

This is the error I keep getting along with a red screen that reads TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

I have tried numerous tutorials after the initial failure with the Google tutorial and all of them result in an error that references the body: GoogleMaps( line. Sorry if this was too long or too vague this is my first ever question and I just started using Stack Overflow today! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please post code blocks instead of screenshots.

Comment: I edited to have the code blocks in let me know if I need to change anything else!

Comment: Android, iOS, or Web?

Comment: @SpencerYahn did you got a solution please share