# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps'). Google flutter maps web

Tags: flutter

Any idea of how to solve the problem [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639016/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-maps-flutter-and-dart)

The platform is a flutter web

Answer (score 1):

Add google maps script to `web/index.html`.

```
<head>
...
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
</head>
```

See [google_maps_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web) for details.

Comment: I have both, `google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.4.0` and `google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8`, and I have the script built as `String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${dotenv.env['GMAP_API_KEY']}';
  var scriptTag = html.document.getElementById("map_script");

  if(scriptTag != null && scriptTag.getAttribute('src') != url){
    scriptTag.setAttribute( 'src', url );
  }
`. But I still get the error. in my index.html I have `<script id="map_script">
    <!--    A script for map api key-->
  </script>`

Answer (score 1):

Debug using terminal instead of using debug console.

Run this in terminal :

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```