# The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building GoogleMap(dirty, dependencies: [Directionality],

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-maps, firebase-authentication

I already input all things I know to add google maps to add maps in flutter mobile application. I already had my login_screen.dart successfully conected with firebase database, and already succeed to show home_page when the page only contain text only. When I input the google map, on debug console showed like this:

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building GoogleMap(dirty, dependencies:
[Directionality], state: _GoogleMapState#587c7):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

The relevant error-causing widget was:
GoogleMap
GoogleMap:file:///D:/AAA%20KULIAH/Semester%205/rpl_agile_implementation/smlog_delivery/lib/pages/home_page.dart:24:11

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
packages/google_maps_flutter_web/src/convert.dart 100:30                          _gmapTypeIDForPluginType
packages/google_maps_flutter_web/src/convert.dart 43:25                           _configurationAndStyleToGmapsOptions
packages/google_maps_flutter_web/src/google_maps_controller.dart 173:32           init
packages/google_maps_flutter_web/src/google_maps_flutter_web.dart 311:8           
packages/google_maps_flutter_web/src/google_maps_flutter_web.dart 311:8           buildViewWithConfiguration
packages/google_maps_flutter/src/google_map.dart 321:47                           build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5583:27                               build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5471:15                               performRebuild
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

This is my main.dart file :

```
`import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smlog_delivery/authentication/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:smlog_delivery/firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}`
```

And this is my login_screen.dart :

```
`import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smlog_delivery/authentication/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:smlog_delivery/firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
`
```

And this is my home_page.dart :

```
`import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:smlog_delivery/global/global_var.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> googleMapCompleterController =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();
  GoogleMapController? controllerGoogleMap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            initialCameraPosition: googlePlexInitialPosition,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController mapController) {
              controllerGoogleMap = mapController;

              googleMapCompleterController.complete(controllerGoogleMap);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

I put the initialCameraPosition: googlePlexInitialPosition code on file global_var.dart in my lib :

```
`import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

String namaUser = "";
//my API Key already inserted to AndroidManifest.xml
String googleMapKey = "...";

const CameraPosition googlePlexInitialPosition = CameraPosition(
  target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
  zoom: 14.4746,
);`
```

I already check there is no error on code, but when i run the application it turned like this. I already successful connecting the flutter with firebase with flutterfire, but for this problem I became confused. Is there something that I forgot to add?

I already opened the flutter documentations in the link, but I am little bit confused to try that. because the documentation only shown that in main.dart only. I don't really know what to do. I will be very grateful for someone who can solve this problem.

Comment: This looks similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69639016/18422887 but unfortunately, there was also no answer there. But have you tried filing an issue to the github repo of the `google_maps_flutter_web` library?

Comment: Though this one had an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72974357/18422887

It says there that you should just **include the Google Map API in the index.html **. Can you try the suggested solution there?